# Django query not working in shell_plus but working in dbshell

Tags: sql, django, sqlite

I have a query that won't return me an expected value, but when I print the query itself, and run it in Dbshell, it does work. I am on Django 1.8.18 with SQLite version 3.11.0

My Recommendation has a Foreign Key on my Car, and I need to get all my Cars that do not have a Recommendation with `is_active=True` AND `description=FOO`. I know I could probably make it work in the other way, but it would be way easier for me to make it work this way.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Recommendation(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I have created a Recommendation linked to my Car id 100, with is_active set to False, and description to FOO

```
Car.objects.exclude(recommendation__is_active=True, recommendation__description="FOO")
```

This query returns me nothing, when I expected it to return Car 100. I decided to print the actual query and try it in dbshell

```
SELECT "myapp_car"."id"
FROM "myapp_car"
WHERE NOT ("myapp_car"."id" IN (SELECT U1."car_id" AS Col1 FROM "myotherapp_recommendation" U1 WHERE U1."description" = 'FOO') AND "myapp_car"."id" IN (SELECT U1."car_id" AS Col1 FROM "myotherapp_recommendation" U1 WHERE U1."is_active" = 'True'))
```

However, this properly works ! It returns me my Car 100

I have also tried with Q, but it didn't work either

```
Car.objects.exclude(Q(recommendation__is_active=True) & Q(recommendation__description="FOO"))
```

It feels like a Django bug, but I'd rather have your opinion

Comment: No, this is simply how *negative* logic works, you should use `|` instead of `&`.

Comment: No. I want to exclude those that are both, not either. And just in case, I have tried `|` but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have written here, is basically *two* JOINs: you exclude `Car` objects that have a `Recommendation` that is *not* `is_active`, and you furthermore exclude `Car`s that have a `Recommendation` (not necessarily the same), that have a `Recommendation` with `description='FOO'`. But those recommendations are not per se the same. This is a consequence of *negative logic*.

## With `EXISTS`

If we want to `JOIN` over the *same* table, we can work with an `EXISTS` subquery:

```
to_exclude = Recommendation.objects.filter(
    car=OuterRef('pk'),
    is_active=True,
    description="FOO",
)
```

Now we can `exclude` the `Car`s for which such `Recommendation` exists:

```
Car.objects.annotate(
    has_recommendation_to_exclude=Exists(to_exclude)
).exclude(
    has_recommendation_to_exclude=False
)
```

## Using a `COUNT`-filter approach

```
Car.objects.annotate(
    nrec=Sum(
        Case(
            When(
                recommendation__is_active=True,
                recommendation__description="FOO",
                then=Value(1)
            ),
            default=Value(0),
            output_field=IntegerField(),
        )
    )
).exclude(nrec__gt=0)
```

Comment: I would agree with you, however, the SQL query, that I print directly from my Django query, does return me the correct result. That's what I don't understand. It is possible that it's because of quotes (because Django won't print quotes when printing queries).

About the Exists, it does seem nice, however, sadly, I can't use it, because it's from 1.11 and I'm on 1.8 (and I can't upgrade immediately, it's a big project using a lot of packages). But thank you anyway

Comment: @ilanouh: well actually the query you post will not always work: it will return `Cars` that have not a recommendation that is set to active, and a recommendation with `"FOO"`. But what if you add say two recommendations for a `Car`: one with `is_active=True`, and *another* with `description="Foo"`, then your dbshell, will filter out that car.

Comment: @ilanouh: we can also construct a query without EXISTS (I will update the answer). But since 1.8 is no longer supported (since april), I really advice you to upgrade, since now your server starts becoming vulnerable to security issues.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, I did have multiple recommendations, one with `description="FOO"` and another with `"is_active=True"`. I figured that's why my Django query didn't take, but, again, my SQL query did work. And even still, I would expect Django and Dbshell results to always be the same. I tried what you updated, but it doesn't work, and I see you removed it now (?). Also, I will update to 1.11 (2+ is too ambitious for us right now) as soon as I can, been wanting to do that since April

Comment: @ilanouh: the edit contains a query that should work for Django-1.8. I'm only saying that I would advice you to upgrade.

Comment: New edit works. I was trying that earlier, and came really close. I was just missing output_field. And I think SQL doesn't work either, I was using the value 'True', when I should have used 1. Thank you very much !